# trying to set a static ip but can't

Tags: command-line, sudo, ip

Every time I try to get into my `/etc/network/interfaces` file, I get a `not a directory` message.

I have not done anything else to it since I have installed the server on to my VM, and I am logged in as root. Am I suppose to type sudo in front?

Comment: what is the output of `file /etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 3):

If you enter `/etc/network`, and run `ls -la`, you will notice that `interfaces` is not formatted like a directory. This is because it is a file containing text.

So, you don't "enter" it, you "edit" it. For example, by running `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: They shouldn't have to use sudo if they're already root. Also I have a feeling `nano /etc/network/interfaces` may be easier for them use to edit if they are a beginner.

Comment: Being completely honest, as a beginner I felt it was necessary to point out that sudo is necessary when editing certain files due to the fact that running commands while signed in as root is generally bad practice, especially for a beginner.